# Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> BluetoothSerial]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bluetooth, ionic4

I'm using in my Ionic 4 app the plugin `'@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx'` for communication with a thermal printer. If I compile the source for an android device with android 7.1.1, it shows this error:

> E/Capacitor/Plugin/Console: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> BluetoothSerial]: 
>         StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> BluetoothSerial]: 
>           NullInjectorError: No provider for BluetoothSerial!
>       Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> BluetoothSerial]: 
>         StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> BluetoothSerial]: 
>           NullInjectorError: No provider for BluetoothSerial!
>           at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (http: //localhost/vendor.js:42939:19)
>           at resolveToken (http: //localhost/vendor.js:43184:24)
>           at tryResolveToken (http: //localhost/vendor.js:43128:16)
>           at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (http: //localhost/vendor.js:43025:20)
>           at resolveToken (http: //localhost/vendor.js:43184:24)
>           at tryResolveToken (http: //localhost/vendor.js:43128:16)
>           at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (http: //localhost/vendor.js:43025:20)
>           at resolveNgModuleDep (http: //localhost/vendor.js:55261:29)
>           at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (http: //localhost/vendor.js:55950:16)
>           at resolveNgModuleDep (http: //localhost/vendor.js:55261:29)

I have only imported it and added the parameter in the constructor.

home.ts code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  infoText:string = '';

  constructor(private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial) {}

  listAllItems()
  {
    this.infoText = 'Hier werden alle Geräte aufgelistet!!!';
  }

  isConnected()
  {
    this.infoText = 'Hier wird angezeigt ob es verbunden ist!!!';
  }
}
```

Does anyone know the cause for the error? Thanks for help.

Comment: *I have only imported it* where?

Comment: Did you run: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial` **and** `npm install @ionic-native/bluetooth-serial`?

Comment: Look at the code, only in home.ts. Ok and the normal place: package.json

Comment: @youri yes. I habe do the same as here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial and like this https://medium.com/@maneeshaindrachapa/bluetooth-serial-interface-with-ionic-66c823792166

Comment: Could you add your `app.module` in your question?

Comment: I can upload the app.module file on monday. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the instructions on the native plugins page there are also some general instructions that you have to follow every time you add a plugin to your project.

They are listed here:

- [Ionic Native Community Edition - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/overview)

What it means is that you need to edit your app.module.ts to import the module into the project. It can then be used by the rest of the app.

```
// app.module.ts
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial/ngx';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    BluetoothSerial
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks i look on monday in the app.modul.ts , then i can say more.

Comment: Hey thanks. BluetoothSerial was not add in providers:[..]. Now work it.